# creating a pipe and writing to gnuplot terminal from c++

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am trying to call the gnuplot from c++. I am using wgnuplot for Windows and VS2005 c++.

The following statement works because it opens the gnuplot terminal

```
FILE *p = _popen("wgnuplot -persist","w");
```

But I cannot write anything there. My terminal is still blank even after running the following code.

```
fprintf(p, "set terminal x11 enhanced\n"); //set appropriate output terminal for the plot 
fprintf(p, "set xlabel 'N'\n");//set xlabel 
fprintf(p, "set ylabel 'error'\n");//set ylabel
```

Could you please tell me what might be the problem, i.e. why the terminal is blank and fprintf() doesn't seem to work?

Thanks,

Boris

Comment: Did you also call `fflush(p)`?

Comment: This is my complete code: FILE *p = _popen("wgnuplot" ,"w");
fprintf(p, "plot sin(x)");
fflush(p);

fflush(stderr);
getchar();
fprintf(p,"exit \n");
_pclose(p);

Answer (score 0):

Check that FILE pointer is not NULL:

```
if(!p)
  // _popen() has failed...
```

Comment: -  pipe 0x10311d68 {_ptr=0x00000000 <Bad Ptr> _cnt=0 _base=0x00000000 <Bad Ptr> ...} _iobuf *

Comment: That is what I get when I debug and check what is in the pipe. I still don't know why fprintf() doesn't write anything to the terminal.

Comment: @Boris so p seem to be ok, but internals seems to be blowing out...
I suggest you to look into error reporting mechanism of the function, it may be due to suppling wrong parameters.

Comment: Microsoft says: The functions return NULL on an error. If the error is an invalid parameter, such as if command or mode is a null pointer, or mode is not a valid mode, errno is set to EINVAL. See the Remarks section for valid modes.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that helps you, but this is my approach of executing gnuplot from my C programs:

1. I create a template file (usually I do not delete it, so that it is easier to troubleshoot), where all the gnuplot commands are are scripted in.
2. I run gnuplot with

   ```
   system("gnuplot <TemplateFile>")
   ```

If you are only interested in creating a plot, that his would do the job. If you are explicitly interested in the approach you described above then just disregard this posting ;)

Cherio Woltan